# Excel: how to count and group rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have an Excel file with **Column A** and **Column B**. Both have people names (**Elizabeth**, **John**, **Michael** and **Robert**).

I need to count each name of Column A and count each name of Column B. And then I need to show each name (**Name** column) with the difference that I counted before (**Difference** column).

In databases it is called *Group By*.

I made this example so it can be easier to explain. It has less than 10 rows but I will use it with a file that has 7000 rows:

[image: Example using LibreOffice]

Comment: Is the difference always going to be Count A - Count B. Is Column B always a subset of Column A? Is there a possibility that item exists in Column B only but not in A? In that case how do you want to show the results? Explore COUNTIF Function and see if it will work here to solve this.

Comment: To add to pat2015's questions: Are the names always aggregated and sorted alphabetically as in the example?  Do all names always appear in both columns?  Is the col A count always >= col B count?  If not, do you care about negative results or do you want the absolute difference?  What version of what application are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have the list of unique names for col D, or does the solution need to generate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,D2)-COUNTIF(B:B,D2)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you get the list of unique names in col D?  The OP describes 7000 rows and doesn't mention having a list of the unique names (actually says both columns are needed).  The safe approach is to either ask for clarification or include generating the list in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**To Count & Group Rows do the followings:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. **To create List of Unique Names**, write this Array formula in Cell `D3`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down.

   ```
      {=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$11, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $A$3:$A$11), 0)), INDEX($B$3:$B$8, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $B$3:$B$8), 0))), "")}
   ```
2. **To count the difference,** write this formula in Cell `E3` & fill down.

   ```
   =COUNTIF($A$3:$A$11,D3)-COUNTIF($B$3:$B$8,D3)
   ```

**Note,** Formula 2 in my post is inspired from @Lee's Answer.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*